# Does apps automatically get translated? If not, how do I approach this problem?

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

Say I have an app that has one label that says "hello". I publish it "worldwide" on the app store.

If someone purchases it in China, and opens it, does the app store auto translate it to "Ni hao".
If not, how do I combat this issue? Do I have to make an app for each country?  Is there a way to auto translate in Xcode/coding?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/localization/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: A single app can serve the purpose, you just need to add localization in your app. Here is a good article to start localizing your app. https://www.raywenderlich.com/250-internationalizing-your-ios-app-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Application do not translate automatically.
You need to use localization.
You set up Localizable.strings (China) and one for English version

English file:
"hello" = "hello"

China file:
"hello" = "Ni hao"

Inside your application you need to use NSLocalizedString

```
static let hello = NSLocalizedString("hello", comment: "Tab Bar title, and navigation bar title for Profile")

label.test = hello
```

Now will translate depends of device language setup

more examples https://www.raywenderlich.com/250-internationalizing-your-ios-app-getting-started